# How to Unreal Engine C++ CustomStruct RemoveAt or Remove UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

#1 or #2

The function is not working but It works fine with inEditor Blueprint
(Write operator==)

```
.h 
TArray<FStruct> StructArray

.cpp
void Func(FStruct struct_2)
{ 
  const uint32 Index = SturctArray.Find(struct_2); // Always Value = 0
  if(StructArray[Index] == struct_2)
  {
   StructArray.RemoveAt(struct_2) // #1
   StructArray.Remove(Index) // #2
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Func` will create a copy of the `FStruct` object passed in. `StructArray` will never contain the copy that was made for function `Func`. To make that work, have `Func` use something that does not create a copy. Like a reference.

Don't use the result of [`TArray.Find()`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/TArray/Find/1/) before checking if it is valid.

[`TArray.RemoveAt()`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/TArray/RemoveAt/1/) expects an index, your code supplies it an object.

[`TArray.Remove()`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/TArray/Remove/) expects on item of the same type used to declare the TArray, your code supplies it an index.

#1

```
void Func(FStruct& struct_2)
{ 
  const uint32 Index = StructArray.Find(struct_2);
  if (Index != INDEX_NONE)
  {
    StructArray.RemoveAt(Index); // #1
  }
}
```

#2

```cpp
void Func(FStruct& struct_2)
{ 
  StructArray.Remove(struct_2); // #2
}
```